# Marvel API Swift4 JSON Decoding

Tags: json, swift, api, nested, decode

I'm making a basic IOS app, based on the "App development with Swift" book from Apple. My app uses the Marvel API. I'm trying to reach the name and the description of the heroes.
The connection with the API works completely and has been tested multiple times. The problem hasn't anything do to with this.

My problem is the fact that the JSON result is 3 times nested, I have no idea how to reach this in Swift 4.

Here is an example of the JSON result of 1 hero. All Heroes can be found in the "result"

[The JSON structure can be found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmhiW.png)

My code has a fatal error:

> Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "results", intValue: nil)

```
let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data,
        response, error) in
        try! jsonDecoder.decode(CharactersContainer.self, 
from: data!) //error here
        if let data = data,
            let char = try? jsonDecoder.decode(CharactersContainer.self, from: data) {
            print(char.characters)
            print("succes")

        } else {
            print("failed")
        }
    }
```

Now here are my models:

```
import Foundation

struct Character: Codable {
    var name: String
    var description: String
    //var url: Image


    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case description
        //case url = "thumbnail"

    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let valueContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CharactersContainer.CodingKeys.self).nestedContainer(keyedBy: Characters.CodingKeys.self, forKey: .characters).nestedContainer(keyedBy: Character.CodingKeys.self, forKey: .characters)
        if let name = try valueContainer.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.name) {
            self.name = name
        } else {
            self.name = ""
        }
        if let description = try valueContainer.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.description) {
            self.description = description
        } else {
            self.description = ""
        }

       // self.url = try valueContainer.decode(URL.self, forKey: CodingKeys.url)

    }
}



struct Characters : Decodable{
    var characters : [Character]
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case characters = "data"
    }
}

struct CharactersContainer : Decodable {
    var characters : Characters
    //var total: Int
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case characters = "results"
        //case total
    }
}
```

I have no idea what I did wrong, since I saw some examples who did the exact same thing.

Thanks for checking in!

Comment: Basically don't `try!` while developing JSON parsing with `Codable`. Add a `do - catch` block and print the `error` instance. It might contain more information than the fatal error. And mapping keys to the same property name (`characters`) in different structs can be confusing

Comment: Valid criticism. I changed the names of the classes to MarvelData and Result

Answer (score 0):

In the JSON, `data` contains the `results` key. The way your keys are set up, it's expecting `results` to contain a `data` key.

`CharactersContainer.CodingKeys.characters` should probably be `"data"`

`Characters.CodingKeys.characters` should probably be `"results"`

---

Edit:

There's another issue in `Character`. It is trying to get a contain keyed by `CharactersContainer.CodingKeys.self` but it should probably be `Character.CodingKeys.self`

Comment: You're right, but if u change it. I still get an error saying:
Thread 5: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "results", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "Cannot get KeyedDecodingContainer<CodingKeys> -- no value found for key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"data\", intValue: nil) (\"data\")", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Can you convert `data` to a string and print it out before you try decoding it? It's possible you're getting a different result from the server that doesn't have a `data` key

Comment: The picture I added here is actually taken from a print.